# trouble with setTimeout in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
function EndSession() {

            window.close();
        };

       setTimeout("EndSession()", 10000);

});
```

Shown above is the code in a child page opened using window.open().

The problem is after ten seconds when it tries to call EndSession, it throws an error
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'EndSession' is undefined"

What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the problem of the old way "string" is that it was looking for the method in the global scope, while the method was defined inside the function used for jQuery `ready`.

We can explicitly pass the function we really want to, if we have a proper reference to it.

Let's try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    var endSession = function() {
        window.close();
    };

    setTimeout(endSession, 10000);
});
```

Although I haven't tried it, maybe even this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    setTimeout(window.close, 10000);
});
```

I'm not sure if you need the jQuery ready at all too, unless you intentionally want to start counting time after the document is fully loaded (which I'd expect to be very quick for a pop-up that closes soon).

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: There is a delay before they let you mark a response as an answer, so I had to come back later :(

Answer (score 3):

that should be like this,

```
setTimeout(EndSession, 10000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VE6GR/1)

Comment: An explanation of why that works and the other doesn't would improve this answer.

Comment: @developer747 Have you tried his demo? It should work like this.

Comment: This worked because in the demo, the `EndSession` passed as parameter was a reference to the function `endSession` defined in a closure. Using `""` around the name, it would be only interpreted after triggering the event and that would be in the global namespace. The parentheses are not the main point here :)

Answer (score 3):

When the timeout event triggers, the code you specified is run in the global namespace.

Your code is `"EndSession()"`, so the browser tries to find a global function with the name `EndSession`. There is no such function, because you defined `EndSession()` inside an anonymous function that you passed to `$(document).ready()`.

So, defining `EndSession` as global will suffice.

```
function EndSession() {
    window.close();
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout("EndSession()", 10000);
});
```

Also, functions that are not constructors should, by convention, start with lowercase letter ;)

Comment: Appendix: If you do not want to pollute global namespace, you can reference the function in a closure. See @MohamedMeligy's answer for this.